# No able to delete the record I want, only the first one

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I'm trying to delete a record. Everything seems all right however, I'm not able to delete the record I want, only the first one.

The code for the view is:

```
    <table class="table">
      <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Inscrito en</th>
          <th>Cambios</th>
       </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        @if (!empty($escuelausuarios))
          @foreach($escuelausuarios as $escuelausuario)
            <tr>
              <td> {{ $escuelausuario->idEscuelaUsuario }} </td>
              <td> {{ $escuelausuario->escuela->strNombreEscuela }} </td>
              <td>


                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" id="delete{{ $escuelausuario->idEscuelaUsuario }}"

                onclick="
                  var resultdelete = confirm ('¿Estas seguro de que deseas eliminar al usuario en ésta escuela?');
                    if (resultdelete)
                    {
                      event.preventDefault();
                      document.getElementById('delete-horario-form').submit();
                    }
                "


                >-</button>
                  <form id="delete-horario-form" action="{{ route('escuelausuarios.destroy',[$escuelausuario->idEscuelaUsuario]) }}"
                    method="POST" style="display: none;">
                      <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete">
                      {{ csrf_field() }}
                  </form>                 

              </td>
            </tr>

          @endforeach
        @endif

      </tbody>
    </table>
```

The controler always get the same Id, so, the record I delete is always the same, the first one.

```
public function destroy($idEscuelaUsuario)
{
    //
    dd($idEscuelaUsuario);
    $escuelaUsuario = EscuelaUsuario::find($idEscuelaUsuario);
    //dd($escuelaUsuario);
    if($escuelaUsuario->delete())
    {
        return back()->withInput()->with('success','Escuela desvinculada del usuario exitosamente');
        //return redirect()->route('usuarios.index')->with('success','Escuela desvinculada del usuario exitosamente');
    }
    return back()->withInput()->with('error','La escuela no pudo desvuncularse');

}
```

In another post I had a similary problem but, it was an edit view and the problem was that the values  never arrived to the modal window,so I changed the Id name for each row and everything worked. In this case, I just need to send the id of the row but it's always the same, the first one of the query.

Please help, I don't have an idea of what's happening.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thats because you have submitted form from id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use ID attribute in foreach loop make sure to have different ids per row

If you use `document.getElementByID` It will always search for the first occurrence of that `ID`

```php
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" id="delete{{ $escuelausuario->idEscuelaUsuario }}" onclick="
              var resultdelete = confirm ('¿Estas seguro de que deseas eliminar al usuario en ésta escuela?');
                if (resultdelete)
                {
                  event.preventDefault();
                  document.getElementById('delete-horario-form{{ $escuelausuario->idEscuelaUsuario }}').submit();
                }
">-</button>

<form id="delete-horario-form{{ $escuelausuario->idEscuelaUsuario }}" action="{{ route('escuelausuarios.destroy',[$escuelausuario->idEscuelaUsuario]) }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
   <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete">
   {{ csrf_field() }}
</form>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, actually I thought of that and implemented but is obvious that something went wrong

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

All the hidden forms has the same id (`"delete-horario-form"`). When delete button is clicked, it will submit the form which have `"delete-horario-form"` as id. But in your code all the ids are same, so it will submit the first one only.

**Solution:**

You have made the button id dynamic `id="delete{{ $escuelausuario->idEscuelaUsuario }}"`, which is not necessary. Button id doesn't make any difference here, but the form id do. By making form id dynamic as like button, it will solved your problem.

```
<table class="table">
      <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Inscrito en</th>
          <th>Cambios</th>
       </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        @if (!empty($escuelausuarios))
          @foreach($escuelausuarios as $escuelausuario)
            <tr>
              <td> {{ $escuelausuario->idEscuelaUsuario }} </td>
              <td> {{ $escuelausuario->escuela->strNombreEscuela }} </td>
              <td>
                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" 
                onclick="var resultdelete = confirm ('¿Estas seguro de que deseas eliminar al usuario en ésta escuela?');
                if (resultdelete)
                {
                     event.preventDefault();
                     document.getElementById("delete{{ $escuelausuario->idEscuelaUsuario }}").submit();
                }"


                >-</button>
                  <form id="delete{{ $escuelausuario->idEscuelaUsuario }}" action="{{ route('escuelausuarios.destroy',[$escuelausuario->idEscuelaUsuario]) }}"
                    method="POST" style="display: none;">
                      <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete">
                      {{ csrf_field() }}
                  </form>                 

              </td>
            </tr>

          @endforeach
        @endif

      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: It will generate dynamic id for form.